# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build during onChange function in dynamic fields

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I was trying to update dynamic fields **onChanged** where I use **setstate()** but I am unable to change controller.text. I am getting data from backend with api and show data in fields in variants list but I am unable to edit the field, maybe  due to this error,
I have get dynamic fields in a **Listview builder**, then **conroller** defined and save value on change in a **Map<String,dynamic>**
my code is-

```
 Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text("Varient", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: AppColor.textDarkColor),),
                    SizedBox(height: 8,),
                    Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      height: 250,
                      child: Form(
                        key: _formKey,
                        child: GridView.builder(
                            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                                maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                                childAspectRatio: 6 / 2, crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                                mainAxisSpacing: 0),
                            itemCount: allAttributes.isEmpty ? 0 : allAttributes.length,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              _controllers.add(new TextEditingController());
                              if(allAttributes[index].label == 'MRP'){
                                widget.productId!=null ?
                                _controllers[index].text = variantfirst[0].mrpPrice:
                                _controllers[index].text = '';
                              }else  if(allAttributes[index].label == 'Discount'){
                                widget.productId!=null ?
                                _controllers[index].text = variantfirst[0].discount:
                                _controllers[index].text = '';
                              }else  if(allAttributes[index].label == 'Sort'){
                                widget.productId!=null ?
                                _controllers[index].text = variantfirst[0].sort:
                                _controllers[index].text = '';
                              }else  if(allAttributes[index].label == 'SKU'){
                                widget.productId!=null ?
                                _controllers[index].text = variantfirst[0].sku:
                                _controllers[index].text = '';
                              }else  if(allAttributes[index].label == 'Weight'){
                                widget.productId!=null ?
                                _controllers[index].text = variantfirst[0].weight:
                                _controllers[index].text = '';
                              }else  if(allAttributes[index].label == 'Unit'){
                                widget.productId!=null ?
                                _controllers[index].text = variantfirst[0].unitType:
                                _controllers[index].text = '';
                              }
                              else if(allAttributes[index].label == 'Price'){
                                widget.productId!=null ?
                                _controllers[index].text = variantfirst[0].price:
                                _controllers[index].text = toPrice;
                                myObject.update(allAttributes[index].variantFieldName, (v) => toPrice, ifAbsent: () => toPrice);
                              }
                              return TextFormField(
                                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                                cursorColor: AppColor.primaryColor,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: AppColor.textDarkColor, fontSize: 16.0,
                                ),
                                validator: (val){
                                  if(allAttributes[index].validation == "true" ){
                                    if(val.isEmpty){
//                                  EasyLoading.showToast(allAttributes[index].label+' is Empty',
//                                      toastPosition: EasyLoadingToastPosition.bottom);
//                              return ;
                                      return allAttributes[index].label +" is empty";
                                    }
                                    return null ;
                                  }
                                },
                                onChanged: (val){
                                    setState(() {
                                      if(allAttributes[index].label=='MRP'){
                                        toPrice = mrp = val+".00";
                                        print(toPrice);
                                        myObject.update(allAttributes[index].variantFieldName, (v) => mrp, ifAbsent: () => mrp);
                                      }else if(allAttributes[index].label=='Discount'){
                                        discount = val+".00";
                                        double result = double.parse(mrp) / double.parse(discount);
                                        double resultno =  double.parse(mrp) - result;
                                        toPrice = resultno.toString();
                                        print(toPrice);
                                        myObject.update(allAttributes[index].variantFieldName, (v) => val, ifAbsent: () => val);
                                      }else if(allAttributes[index].label=='Price'){
                                        _controllers[index].text = toPrice;
                                        myObject.update(allAttributes[index].variantFieldName, (v) => toPrice, ifAbsent: () => toPrice);
                                      }
                                      else{
                                        myObject.update(allAttributes[index].variantFieldName, (v) => val, ifAbsent: () => val);
                                      }
                                    });
                                 

                                },
                                keyboardType: allAttributes[index].type =='number'
                                    ? TextInputType.number : TextInputType.text ,
                                controller: _controllers[index],
                                maxLines: 1,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                    labelText: allAttributes[index].label,
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: AppColor.textLightColor)),
                              );
                            }
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: You don't need to call setState if you want to update the controller's text.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, I have removed  setstate but still same error

Comment: Why are you doing `_controllers[index].text = ...` inside the `itemBuilder` function? This should be done while initiating your widget or while reacting to an event.
Also, in order to make it easier to help you, you should try to only keep the minimum amount of code to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Gpack I was getting dynamic fields fron api then according to the number of attributes I have use Listview builder, then for each textfield on change there are events as subtract on change MRP -Discount =Price to save in price